# Specifying properties to be updated on bulk merge (update)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Basically, what I am trying to achieve is the next:

1. If there is **no** record with the given ID then the record gets inserted.
2. If there **is** a record with the given ID, then I must update its status(one of the columns).

This is my model:

```
public class CustomerTransaction
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public TransactionStatuses StatusId { get; set; }
    
    public TransactionTypes TypeId { get; set; }
    
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    
    public decimal AmountOfMoney { get; set; }
}
```

I have got the following code right now:

```
await _context.Transactions.BulkMergeAsync(request.NewTransactions,
    options =>
    {
        options.IgnoreOnMergeUpdateExpression = t => t.Id;
        options.IgnoreOnMergeUpdateExpression = t => t.FullName;
        options.IgnoreOnMergeUpdateExpression = t => t.TypeId;
        options.IgnoreOnMergeUpdateExpression = t => t.AmountOfMoney;
    })
```

If I understand everything correctly, I need something that specifies what to update instead of what to ignore on update to make it work as I expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IgnoreOnMergeUpdateExpression` option must be specified only once (otherwise, you keep overridden the value). However, you can add multiple properties by using an anonymous type.

```
await _context.Transactions.BulkMergeAsync(request.NewTransactions,
    options =>
    {
        options.IgnoreOnMergeUpdateExpression = t => new { t.Id, t.FullName, t.TypeId, t.AmountOfMoney};
    })
```

---

**EDIT:** Updating answer with a newest option

Since the v5.2.13, this is now possible to specify columns that you want to update:

```
await _context.Transactions.BulkMergeAsync(request.NewTransactions,
    options =>
    {
        options.OnMergeUpdateInputExpression = t => new { t.StatusId };
    })
```